# MySQL WHERE in IF Statement of View

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a view of 3 tables. There is one line that is messing up everything and I can't get it right. Its in the "IF" statement below. I know I can't use WHERE inside an if statement, but that is what I'm trying to achieve.

Table 'c' (The `qms_dpus` table) is a table that stores ERRORS for each job. What I'm trying to do is say

"for every job that is inside table 'a', check table 'c' to see if the JOBNUM columns match AND the IS_COMPLETE column is 0. If that is true then put a 1 in this new Column `OPEN_DPUS`. If it is false, then put a 0 in the column"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `view_qms_linea` AS SELECT 
  a.ID AS `ID`,
  a.JID AS `JID`,
  b.HPL AS `HPL`,
  b.LINE AS `LINE`,
  a.PAREA AS `PRODAREA`,
  a.JOBNUM AS `JOBNUM`,
  b.MODELNUMBER AS `MODELNUMBER`,
  b.CUSTOMER AS `CUSTOMER`,
  b.PM_AE AS `PM_AE`,
  b.PM_PE AS `PM_PE`,
  b.PM_DE AS `PM_DE`,
  b.PM_EE AS `PM_EE`,
  b.PM_ED AS `PM_ED`,
  b.PM_CE AS `PM_CE`,
  IF(c.IS_COMPLETE=0 WHERE c.JOBNUM LIKE a.JOBNUM, 1, 0) AS `OPEN_DPUS`

FROM `gen_jobs_in_production` a, `gen_jobs_table` b, `qms_dpus` c

WHERE 
  a.JOBNUM LIKE b.WO
AND 
  b.LINE = 1
AND 
  a.PAREA != 4
AND 
  a.PAREA <= 7;
```

When i remove the IF statement (and the reference to table 'c') the code works great and provides me with what I need aside from the column `OPEN_DPUS`, but if I replace the IF statement with this:

```
IF(c.JOBNUM LIKE a.JOBNUM AND c.IS_COMPLETE=0,1,0) AS `OPEN_DPUS`
```

My view provides me with all of the data, but instead of being 12 records (currently), It repeats every record 12 times and repeats that pattern infinitely.

I would love to display my table structure, but I have many columns and would only make this more confusing...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query was missing `join` conditions. Hence it was returning you the cross joined results of the 3 tables in your query. Try the query below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `view_qms_linea` AS SELECT 
 a.ID AS `ID`,
 a.JID AS `JID`,
 b.HPL AS `HPL`,
 b.LINE AS `LINE`,
 a.PAREA AS `PRODAREA`,
 a.JOBNUM AS `JOBNUM`,
 b.MODELNUMBER AS `MODELNUMBER`,
 b.CUSTOMER AS `CUSTOMER`,
 b.PM_AE AS `PM_AE`,
 b.PM_PE AS `PM_PE`,
 b.PM_DE AS `PM_DE`,
 b.PM_EE AS `PM_EE`,
 b.PM_ED AS `PM_ED`,
 b.PM_CE AS `PM_CE`,
--change from here
 IF(c.IS_COMPLETE = 0, 1, 0) AS `OPEN_DPUS`
 FROM `gen_jobs_in_production` a 
JOIN `gen_jobs_table` b ON  a.JOBNUM = b.WO
JOIN `qms_dpus` c ON c.jobnum = a.jobnum 
WHERE b.LINE = 1
AND a.PAREA != 4
AND a.PAREA <= 7;
```

Comment: You are right to use the JOIN though...there is just probably something with my structure (I'm not referencing the right columns).

Comment: the `join` on tables `a` and `b` should be re-looked at.